# Rails console doesn't work "You may have encountered a bug"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I search if the question had been already asked but I didn't find anything. I have create an application using ruby version 2.3.0 and rails version 5.0.0.1,

When I run this commande

```
rails console
```

And I try to access db like that :

```
Post.all
User.all
```

Or other command line I have this enormous error (sorry for all these lines :

```
/Users/marchardantonin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:27: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x00000000000110
ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-darwin16]

-- Crash Report log information --------------------------------------------
   See Crash Report log file under the one of following:                    
     * ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter                                         
     * /Library/Logs/CrashReporter                                          
     * ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports                                     
     * /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports                                      
   for more details.                                                        
Don't forget to include the above Crash Report log file in bug reports.     

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0061 p:---- s:0252 e:000251 CFUNC  :initialize
c:0060 p:---- s:0250 e:000249 CFUNC  :new
c:0059 p:0186 s:0245 e:000244 METHOD /Users/marchardantonin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:
c:0058 p:0028 s:0238 e:000237 METHOD /Users/marchardantonin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection
c:0057 p:0027 s:0235 e:000234 METHOD /Users/marchardantonin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection
c:0056 p:0025 s:0232 e:000231 METHOD /Users/marchardantonin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection
c:0055 p:0018 s:0227 e:000226 METHOD /Users/marchardantonin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection
c:0054 p:0016 s:0222 e:000220 METHOD /Users/marchardantonin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection
c:0053 p:0035 s:0217 e:000213 METHOD /Users/marchardantonin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection
c:0052 p:0046 s:0211 e:000210 METHOD /Users/marchardantonin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection
c:0051 p:0015 s:0205 e:000204 METHOD
```

....... (other lines)

```
 1666 /Users/marchardantonin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/relation/predicate_builder/range_handler.rb
 1667 /Users/marchardantonin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/relation/predicate_builder/relation_handler.rb
 1668 /Users/marchardantonin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/relation/predicate_builder.rb
 1669 /Users/marchardantonin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/table_metadata.rb

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html
```

Comment: It seems to be a problem with SQLite, how did you installed it? Could you try other DB? Postgres maybe?

Comment: @Leito I didn't know that I had to install it ! I have to do a command line ?

Comment: It looks like the SQLite gem is already installed, but broken. You could try `gem install sqlite3` to re-install it. Did you copy your gems or RVM from another machine or something?

Comment: @JimStewart Thank you for your answer, I try gem install sqlite3 but it doesn't work, I still have this error

Comment: Ok I find the solution, I put the gem in :development, :test do .... and it work fine !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try like this it workes for me

```
gem uninstall sqlite3
gem install sqlite3
```

Answer (score 10):

If you are using Chip M1

> sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi

Then

> arch -x86_64 pod install

Answer (score 3):

that's right ,edit Gemfile put

```
  gem 'sqlite3'
```

to

```
 group :development, :test do
    gem 'sqlite3'
 end
```

and

```
rails console
```

would be used for me! thanks!

Comment: the FAMMMM works for me. And uninstall and install not works.. thanks FAMMMM

Answer (score 2):

Input `spring stop` before `rails c`

or just remove `gem spring` in Gemfile.

Just try it!

Here you can find more about it:

https://github.com/sparklemotion/sqlite3-ruby/issues/195

https://github.com/rails/spring/issues/493

Comment: reinstalling sqlite3 not working for me but this solution fixed the bug (rails5)

Comment: Similar to @Dude, rails 5 without sqlite3, stoping (and restarting) `spring` fixed my issue. No crash report though, I don't know where this is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

If you still run into issues, try the following steps:

- Install webpacker using npm by running this command: npm i
  @rails/webpacker
  Run bundle install
  Note: You may need to eliminate the version designation. If so, do the following:
- In your Gemfile: change the line with the webpacker gem into: gem
  webpacker

  ```
  Delete the gemfile.lock file
  Run bundle install
  ```
- Manually add a file called webpacker.yml to the config directory
  (final path: ./config/webpacker.yml).

  ```
  Add this text to the webpacker.yml file:
  ```

development:
dev_server:
host: localhost
port: 3000