# iOS - CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding - after latest flutter upgrade

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I am getting this error after I upgraded flutter. Before upgrading everything was working normal on both iOS and android. Now my project is not building in iOS.

Below is my terminal info.

pod setup --verbose

```
    WARNING: CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding.
Consider adding the following to ~/.profile:

export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

pod install --verbose

```
WARNING: CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding.
Consider adding the following to ~/.profile:

export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

[!] No `Podfile' found in the project directory.


/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:151:in `verify_podfile_exists!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:46:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/claide-1.0.2/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `<main>'
```

locale

```
LANG=
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69070537/getting-error-while-run-flutter-app-in-ios check this out, cocoapods 10.0.1 works

Comment: Setting the `export LANG` settings in the .zshrc didn't work for me, so I ended up with: `$ LANG=en_US.UTF-8 <pod command>`. Source: [cocoaPods issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6333#issuecomment-268522581)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

finally i have solved this with below steps

1. export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
2. opened project in Xcode and cleaned
   it.
3. opened iOS folder in mac terminal and ran pod install
4. it gave me warming of using ios 9.0 so i updated it to 10.0
5. ran `flutter build ios`
6. project build successfully
7. opened Runner.xcworkspace in xode
8. clicked on run - this time Xcode again installed pod automatically

and Solved.

Comment: where should i add this export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

Comment: "1." is the question and you have answered the question with the question statement.

Comment: For fish shell users, add `set -gx  LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8` to your ~/.config/fish/config.fish file.

Answer (score 251):

1. Open Terminal
2. Type `open ~/.zshrc` (or `open ~/.profile` if you don't use zsh)

It seems that `LANG="en_US.UTF-8"` alone isn't enough, so you have to set:

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

3. Save the file
4. Go back to Terminal and type `source ~/.zshrc` and type `locale`
5. You can now safely run pod update or pod install

Comment: possibly need to restart Android Studio after applying the change.

Comment: Definetely @Ber

Comment: I had to make new .zshrc file in home and after making all changes mentioned, restarted the system. It Worked...

Comment: @AjmalHasan you could have just sourced the new update without restarting the system (if you don't need to) by executing this in the terminal session:

`
source ~/.zshrc
`

Comment: it worked like rick sanchez portal gun

Comment: This doesn't work. I put it in both files and when hitting the "debug" icon in Android Studio, it still gives the error. Doing it from a terminal also does, and I restarted the mac. Does Android studio run under another user on macOS ?

Answer (score 40):

#### **After one day of struggle finally i found the full solution**

Follow these steps to solve this issue

1. Unhide filles in Mac using `Cmd + Shift + dot`.
2. Go to Macintosh HD -> User -> (Your user ).
3. Search for `.zshrc`
4. Open it with any editor (I recommend VS code)
5. Under.   `#User configuration` comment out `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8`.
6. Open your flutter project and manually delete Pods folder, Podfile, Podfile.lock. (back-up all podfiles)
7. Restart your Mac and run your flutter application
8. Run `pod install`
9. It will automatically create podfile and its new config in UTF - 8 encoding
10. Enjoy and chill i got your back !!!!!

Comment: Thanks, It works for me... save my time... Note: make sure you don't forgot to restart your system.

Comment: It did solve the issue, but what caused it, that my app was running fine a few minutes ago.

Comment: If this export LANG=en_US.UTF-8 does not work then you can use export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8

Comment: removing Podfile.lock was enough

Answer (score 20):

1. Clean files with `flutter clean`
2. Type `vim .zshrc` in your terminal. This should open up your `.zshrc` profile. Type `I` to insert something. Then, simply paste in export `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` and hit <kbd>ESC</kbd> to get out and then type `:wq` to save and quit.
3. Opened project folder, next open iOS folder in mac terminal and run `pod install`
4. It may give warning of using ios 9.0 so update it to 10.0, for that open Podfile in text edit and uncomment or change
   `# platform :ios, '9.0' to` platform :ios, '10.0'
5. Run `flutter build iOS` in the main root project through the terminal.
6. Run main root file eg. `flutter run`

**If you are facing a problem with Flutter. Try this solution**

1. Delete the Podfile, Podfile.lock, Pods folder, Runner.xcworkspace
2. `flutter clean`
3. `flutter build ios`

Comment: I get the following when i install pod [NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: https://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

[IMPORTANT]
Don't forget to include the Crash Report log file under
DiagnosticReports directory in bug reports.

Comment: Hey @MohamedAbdul-Malik, refer this link for some help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40770482/13400029

Comment: This worked for me on macOS montery

Answer (score 10):

*To iterate on Shruti Tupkari's answer* ~ To add in `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8` to your terminal it needs to be added to a profile such as `.zshrc` , `.bashrc` , or `.bash_profile` .

To do this simply use `vim`

**So try**

```
vim .zshrc
```

This should open up your `.zshrc` profile. Type 'i' to insert something.

Then simply paste in `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8` hit esc to get out and then type `:wq` to save and quit

Try and run your app again. If you get the error, repeat the same steps on the other profiles in your computer.

---

*Here's some information on how to use vim*

https://www.howtoforge.com/vim-basics

Answer (score 7):

**Solving Cocoapods UTF-8 error: (Detailed explanation)**

We need to change the locale of the terminal to UTF-8.

Step 1: Open the terminal, type locale, press enter, and check what locale it shows.

Step 2: If it's a bash terminal, change it to a zsh terminal,

Step 3: Then open finder, go to mac HD, users, folder with your username, and press command+shift+. to open hidden files

Step 4: Create or open a file named .zshrc

Step 5: Paste this there:

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Step 6: Save it by command + s

Step 7: Then open the terminal again and check by typing, locale and pressing enter (Then you can either keep it open or close the terminal)

Step 8: If it shows some other locale instead of UTF-8, then paste the below 3 lines and press enter:

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Step 9: Then open Android Studio, go to the terminal and paste the same above 3 lines, and press enter

Step 10: Then on your project file, go to the ios folder, right-click on it, and open in the terminal, then in the terminal, do paste the same above 3 lines and press enter

Step 11: Now you can install pods in this terminal by typing, pod install.

Now it will work, if you still get the same error, go to tools -> flutter -> flutter clean and restart android studio by clicking on File -> restart ide or a similar one.

Then on your project, right-click on the ios folder and open the terminal, type locale, and press enter, if it's not in UTF-8 now, then from step 9 again up to step 11, it will work now. You can run your app on iOS devices now.

My repo -> https://github.com/anantha-eswar/

Answer (score 6):

If adding `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8` doesn't help, try `export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"`

Credits:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6333#issuecomment-551052399

Answer (score 6):

In my case the following needed to be added to `.bash_profile` instead of the other suggested files.

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: Same here. Tried .profile, .zprofile, .zshrc. Worked with bash_profile

Comment: This works for me macOS monterey

Answer (score 4):

```
vim ~/.profile 

export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8

source ~/.profile
```

Answer (score 4):

1- open the required file

```
    vim ~/.zshrc
```

2- add:

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8

export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8

3- Restart the terminal: 

        source ~/.zshrc
4- Restart Android Studio
```

Answer (score 3):

The proper solution, without re-installing anything, can be found:

- here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69160445/3821002
- and here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69376499/3821002

The crux is to use `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8`.

The links above explain how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

if you use Android Studio, then open terminal in it with:

```
nano ~/.profile
```

add these values:

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

and it's very important: now you need to close Android Studio and open it again, then you will be able to make a project

Comment: no effect, system restart required?

Answer (score 1):

After upgrading mac os big sur version I get this error when I try to build ios unity.

If you don't have the file .profile, you can create new file .profile in `/Users/"user-name"/.profile`

step 1: open terminal. create new file .profile

```
$ cd
$ touch .profile
```

step 2: edit .profile.add

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

in .profile

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this error only occurs when I use the **android Studio terminal** to run the flutter ios app.
so instead, I used **Mac Terminal** to run the flutter ios app, and it's working perfectly fine.

To run the flutter app from the terminal use the below command:

```
flutter run
```

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this issue, you can follow the instructions in the warning message and add the following line to your ~/.profile file:

```html
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

This will set the encoding to UTF-8 for your terminal session, which should allow CocoaPods to work properly with your Flutter application.

After adding the line to your ~/.profile file, save the changes and run the following command to reload the profile:

For Bash

```html
source ~/.profile
```

For Zsh

```html
source ~/.zshrc
```

Answer (score 1):

Run this in the terminal

for mac users using zsh

```
echo 'export LANG=en_US.UTF-8' >> ~/.zprofile 
source ~/.zprofile
```

for Linux users using bash

```
echo 'export LANG=en_US.UTF-8' >> ~/.bash_profile 
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, you might want to find either your ~/.bash_profile (for bash) or ~/.zshrc (for zsh) and add the export line that you put in your ~/.profile
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

That was all I had to do.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem only in android studio. When I switched to the terminal outside Android Studio it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just open your terminal
and enter the below command

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `.zshrc` file didn't work for me, so I ended up with executing the cmd with specific language UTF-8 definition:

```
$ LANG=en_US.UTF-8 <pod command>
```

Source: [cocoaPods issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6333#issuecomment-268522581)

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall cocoapods
Installed by brew

```
brew uninstall cocoapods
```

Installed with gem

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
```

Install cocoapods version 1.10.2 (stable version)

```
sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.10.2
```

When I install with this command, it report the following error
You don't have write permissions into the /usr/bin directory
To solve this error, I use the following command

```
sudo  gem install cocoapods -v 1.10.2 -n /usr/local/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution Working in my MacBook Pro 2023(14").

1. open Terminal
2. Run Command `vim ~/.zshrc`
3. Insert 2 Statements(Using i Key): `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` | `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8`
4. Close & save it use Esc + :wq!
5. Run Command `source ~/.zshrc`
6. Now you're good to go

Answer (score 0):

Forget all these solutions. only in two steps

1- In your Android studio terminal "That's what I used", type

```
locale
```

2- Then It will display lists, type in your terminal again

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

And yeah. your problem has been solved :)

Answer (score -1):

I have figured out the latest solution that works fine in 2022

1. Open iOS folder in terminal
2. Run command pod install, and let the process complete.

   ```
    pod install
   ```
3. This works fine, if not try restarting the device