# Unicode Normalization not appropriate for ASCII-8BIT

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

```
13: from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
12: from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
11: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0.beta.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
10: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0.beta.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
9: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:324:in `run'
8: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:337:in `rescue in run'
7: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:396:in `handle_exception'
6: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0.beta.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:66:in `report_error'
5: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0.beta.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:30:in `report'
4: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0.beta.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:105:in `markdown_podfile'
3: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0.beta.2/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:226:in `podfile_path'
2: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0.beta.2/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:166:in `installation_root'
1: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0.beta.2/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:166:in `unicode_normalize'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/unicode_normalize/normalize.rb:141:in `normalize': Unicode Normalization not appropriate for ASCII-8BIT (Encoding::CompatibilityError)
```

I am Facing these errors, don't know why when I run pod update it gives me this error. Any solution??

Comment: update  coca pod  resolved my issue

Comment: Facing the same issue ....  update coca pod didn't helped .... pod install not happening. any solution please !

Comment: To me, it started after I updated cocoapods to latest 1.11.0. I had to downgrade it to 1.10.2 to "fix" it.

Comment: please update cocoa pod its solved

Comment: @Iqbal downgrade it to 1.10.2 didn't worked for me still getting the same error

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I fixed it doing this:

I uninstalled completely cocoapods (my version was 1.11.0)

`gem list --local | grep cocoapods`

> cocoapods-core (1.11.0)
> cocoapods-deintegrate (1.0.5)
> cocoapods-downloader (1.5.0)
> cocoapods-plugins (1.0.0)
> cocoapods-search (1.0.1)
> cocoapods-trunk (1.6.0)
> cocoapods-try (1.2.0)

`sudo gem uninstall cocoapods`

`sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-core`

`sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-deintegrate`

`sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-downloader`

`sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-plugins`

`sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-search`

`sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-trunk`

`sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-try`

Then i installed cocoapods version 1.10.1 (you can try with more versions under 1.11.0 if you need)

`sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.10.1`

Comment: Works good, Thanks Esteban López.

Comment: Had this issue compiling an iOS game from Unity version 2020.3.14f1. Happened right after I upgraded cocoapods / XCode / MacOS. This fixed it.

Comment: This works but sets your tooling back permanently. https://stackoverflow.com/a/69160445/1224741 is proper.

Comment: Worked like a charm. I've installed cocapods in external drive and was trying to uninstall/install in main drive.

Answer (score 135):

This issues appeared in Cocoapods 1.11.0 and as many already noticed rolling back to 1.10.2 fixes the issue. But the original issue comes from wrong locale set in the terminal. It has to be a UTF-8-based locale.

You can run 'locale' in the terminal to check current locale settings. It should be something like this:

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

If you have ascii-based locales set or "C" (which is also an ascii locale) then run

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

If you prefer some other locale (not en_US) then run `locale -a` to see the list of available options and pick UTF-8 locale you prefer.

Actually CocoaPods warns that UTF-8 locale is required:

```
WARNING: CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding.
    Consider adding the following to ~/.profile:

    export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

But before 1.11.0 it was required only in case you use pods which contain non-ascii symbols in their names (Chinese for example) but starting 1.11.0 it become more strict. There is a discussion on Cocoapods GitHub about it:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/10939

Comment: This should be the marked answer. Thank you

Comment: Excellent answer. Indeed, this is better than CocoaPods's own guidance, quoted above, which only indicates that LANG is to be set. Only by setting all locale settings ala this answer was my problem solved.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help. "locale" command prints everything right, but I still get this error in Unity build with Google Dependency Resolver. Can't find what's wrong, so downgrading CocoaPods.

Comment: @luvjungle, I'd suggest verifying locale settings in the build environment itself by putting 'locale' invocation into the build pipeline, if you have not done this already. But it really may be something else in your case, I just described my investigation and solution that helped me.

Comment: Same problem with IntelliJ + Flutter, I can't find out what shell/env it's using to run the build commands, but neither .profile, nor .zshrc, nor .bashrc, nor IntelliJ's own terminal env settings matter....

Comment: @MarianTheisen I have the exact same problem. Only with IntelliJ + Flutter. Did you figure it out?

Comment: This should be accept as correct answer, thanks @ViacheslavKormushkin for saving me, i have been trying to find solution for 2 days.

Answer (score 104):

The answer of 
[Vyacheslav Kormushkin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69160445/3821002) worked for me.

Concretely, what I did was:

- open Terminal
- type `open ~/.zshrc` (or .profile if you don't use zsh)
- add `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8`, and save the file
- go back to Terminal
- type `source ~/.zshrc`
- type `locale`

==> The locale will now be fixed

==> You can now safely run `pod update` or `pod install`

Comment: Thank you, these steps resolved the issue for me after I created the .profile and added this line. I was building from Unity for iOS.

Comment: this is great solution. Thank you.
if you do not find . zshrc this file just use "vim" command and add export line.
It will work like charm after android studio restart.

Comment: Was having issues in react-native ios folder. Thanks to this, got it working.

Comment: I had this issue for my React Native project after installing React Navigation library. These steps solved problem successfully! Thanks a lot.

Comment: I had to restart the AS after these steps. But the issue was solved! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem but using `React Native`, the following worked for me(direct):

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8 pod install
```

Answer (score 11):

**First solution is, to remove your current version of the cocoapods and rolling back to 1.10.2**

To remove your current version, you could just run:

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
```

then you can install the 1.10.2 version of cocoa pods via the following command:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.10.2
```

**The second solution is, to install the  cocoapods via Homebrew with the following command:**

```
brew install cocoapods
```

Comment: you saved my half day buddy. uninstalling and installing specific version helps me.

Answer (score 2):

If you are here because of the failure outputs from Github actions. Try my solution:

add this to the top level of your github workflow yml file:

```
env:
  LANG: en_US.UTF-8
```

ref: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/environment-variables

Answer (score 1):

if you have installed cocoapods using brew, run:

```
brew remove cocoapods
```

after that, install cocoapods using gem:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.10.1
```

Comment: Wow! you are a genius .
Finally my issue got solved, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are experiencing this just with android studio, go to settings and change the configuration of the terminal Shell path.

1. Open settings
2. Search terminal or navigate to Tools -> Terminal
3. Change the Shell Path from **/bin/bash** to **/bin/zsh**
4. Apply and close

There is no need to uninstall anything.

[image: Andriod studio terminal configuration]

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and I added export LANG=en_US.UTF-8 in my **.profile** also, tried all other options. Finally, I tried invalidating the cache and it worked for me.

Steps to invalidate the cache:

1. Android Studio File->Invalidate Caches
2. In the new pop-up check the box whichever you want to clear. Click Invalidate and Restart.

After the IDE restart, the pod install got succeeded.