# Kmm suddenly unable to run in xcode

Tags: swift, cocoapods, kotlin-multiplatform

So I have a project that is suddenly failing. I've done `git stash` to prove it wasn't my change. I've blown cocoa pods away from orbit to no effect.

```
Showing All Messages

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/unicode_normalize/normalize.rb:141:in `normalize': Unicode Normalization not appropriate for ASCII-8BIT (Encoding::CompatibilityError)
```

the top of `~/.zshrc`

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: Check this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68809929/unicode-normalization-not-appropriate-for-ascii-8bit

Comment: This issue actually fixed it 

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-54408/CocoaPod-integration-broken-from-Cocoapods-version-1.11.0#focus=Comments-27-6507239.0-0