# Cocoapods installation failure. Cocoapods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding

Tags: ios, firebase, unity-game-engine, cocoapods

To give you some context, I have an Unity project that I want to build for IOS. I have to use Cocoapods because I have Firebase in my Unity project. Now when I build my game, I get this error:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oslE.png)

When using "locale" in my terminal I get this result with empty LANG [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6ody.png).

The error and most information on the internet tells me to do "Export LANG=en_US.UTF-8", but when I try this and do a Unity build again, the error stays because locale is empty again when checking in the terminal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS - CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding - after latest flutter upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59405671/ios-cocoapods-requires-your-terminal-to-be-using-utf-8-encoding-after-latest)

Comment: No, because I allready visited that link and probably tried every solution in their, but atleast thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same issue, resolved myself by modifying ~/.bash_profile instead of ~/.profile. The issue was introduced happening sometime over the last 3 (??) months since I last built a firebase project.

Comment: Thank you, after the direction you sent me in and a bit more research, I found out that my .profile folder was missing. After getting to know how to create one and filling it in (export LANG=en_US.UTF-8), it was then a simple new Unity build and poof begone error.

Comment: Modifying .bash_profile instead of .profile fixed this issue for me.  thanks!