# How to solved this 'Error output from CocoaPods" problem?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, cocoapods

When I am using vs code that time ios simulator worked fine but When the same project wanted to run on Android Studio for Flutter application development that time I faced this kind of problem. I could not understand what will be the proper solution for this.

```
Running pod install...
CocoaPods' output:
↳
      CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in the repo update

Error output from CocoaPods:
↳
        WARNING: CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding.
        Consider adding the following to ~/.profile:

        export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
        
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/unicode_normalize/normalize.rb:141:in `normalize': Unicode Normalization not appropriate for ASCII-8BIT (Encoding::CompatibilityError)
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:166:in `unicode_normalize'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:166:in `installation_root'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:226:in `podfile_path'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:105:in `markdown_podfile'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:30:in `report'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:66:in `report_error'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:396:in `handle_exception'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:337:in `rescue in run'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:324:in `run'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
        from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/unicode_normalize/normalize.rb:141:in `normalize': Unicode Normalization not appropriate for ASCII-8BIT (Encoding::CompatibilityError)
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:166:in `unicode_normalize'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:166:in `installation_root'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:226:in `podfile_path'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:205:in `podfile'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:160:in `verify_podfile_exists!'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:46:in `run'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
        from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.
```

What is the problem and why it's not working properly?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/59409064/15117201

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS - CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding - after latest flutter upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59405671/ios-cocoapods-requires-your-terminal-to-be-using-utf-8-encoding-after-latest)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i have solved this with below steps

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
opened project in Xcode and cleaned it.
opened iOS folder in mac terminal and ran pod install
it gave me warming of using ios 9.0 so i updated it to 10.0
ran flutter build ios
project build successfully
opened Runner.xcworkspace in xode
clicked on run - this time Xcode again installed pod automatically
and Solved.
```