# Flutter - cocoapods error even with new project

Tags: xcode, flutter, dart

I spend hours and hours, I created new project were it works fine but if I added any package to pupspec.yaml then I will stuck in the to much error lines, I don't know how to solve it, I've tried many solutions but don't know why it happened just today please help me
I'm using macOS M1, all the solutions I tried but no lucks
this error comes only in Iphone emulator but for android no problem!!

I tried

```
  export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
 export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
 export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

nothing works

```
 Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 Pro in debug mode...
Running pod install...
Error output from CocoaPods:
↳
    WARNING: CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding.
    Consider adding the following to ~/.profile:

    export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
    
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/unicode_normalize/normalize.rb:141:in `normalize': Unicode Normalization not appropriate for ASCII-8BIT (Encoding::CompatibilityError)
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:166:in `unicode_normalize'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:166:in `installation_root'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:226:in `podfile_path'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:105:in `markdown_podfile'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:30:in `report'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:66:in `report_error'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:396:in `handle_exception'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:337:in `rescue in run'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:324:in `run'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `load'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `<main>'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/unicode_normalize/normalize.rb:141:in `normalize': Unicode Normalization not appropriate for ASCII-8BIT (Encoding::CompatibilityError)
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:166:in `unicode_normalize'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:166:in `installation_root'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:226:in `podfile_path'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:205:in `podfile'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:160:in `verify_podfile_exists!'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:46:in `run'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `load'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Maybe this questions answer may help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59405671/ios-cocoapods-requires-your-terminal-to-be-using-utf-8-encoding-after-latest

Comment: I tried it exactly but Im getting the same error

Comment: Did you try cleaning the project? 1. flutter clean, 2. delete /iOS/Pods, 3. delete /iOS/Podfile.lock, 4. flutter build ios.

Comment: yes I deleted every thing, I even created new project i works fine but if I added any package like font_awsome or any one after cupertino_icons it will crash again with the same error

Comment: Okay so you can try below steps as well.
1: uninstall cocoapods using : "sudo gem uninstall cocoapods"
2: install latest version of cocoapods using : "sudo gem install cocoapods:{version}"
3: Delete podfile, podfile.lock and pods directory

Comment: Ive installed the latest version but still getting the same error I already tried this before