# Android studio cant find Podfile

Tags: ios, flutter, android-studio, cocoapods

Im trying to run `pod install` in a flutter project on android studio. Its throwing an error that `No Podfile found in the project directory.`, although when i run `pod init` there is an error `Existing Podfile found in directory`!

Of course, there is a `ios/Podfile` file.

[image: terminal capture]

Please help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS - CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding - after latest flutter upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59405671/ios-cocoapods-requires-your-terminal-to-be-using-utf-8-encoding-after-latest)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I didnt clone the project to my `flutter` folder. Now when it in the correct folder, it is working (still dont know why)