# 'Error Output From CocoaPods' When Run Flutter Apps On iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods

I clone my flutter apps from GitHub,it worked on android. When I try to run on iOS, there is some issue. Below is the result when I try run the code. I don't know how to debug.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone SE (3rd generation) in debug mode...
Running pod install...
Error output from CocoaPods:
↳
        WARNING: CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding.
        Consider adding the following to ~/.profile:

        export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
        
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/unicode_normalize/normalize.rb:141:in `normalize': Unicode Normalization not appropriate for ASCII-8BIT (Encoding::CompatibilityError)
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:166:in `unicode_normalize'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:166:in `installation_root'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:226:in `podfile_path'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:105:in `markdown_podfile'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:30:in `report'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:66:in `report_error'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:396:in `handle_exception'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:337:in `rescue in run'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:324:in `run'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
        from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/unicode_normalize/normalize.rb:141:in `normalize': Unicode Normalization not appropriate for ASCII-8BIT (Encoding::CompatibilityError)
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:166:in `unicode_normalize'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:166:in `installation_root'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:226:in `podfile_path'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:205:in `podfile'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:160:in `verify_podfile_exists!'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:46:in `run'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
        from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone SE (3rd generation).
```

Comment: did you installed pods from ios directory ? by this command? => pod install

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS - CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding - after latest flutter upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59405671/ios-cocoapods-requires-your-terminal-to-be-using-utf-8-encoding-after-latest)