# Flutter project failed to run on iOS when I install dart/flutter package to it

Tags: flutter, xcode, dart, cocoapods

I just install android studio, Xcode, cocoapod and flutter/Dart SDK. When I create a new flutter project it run fine on both iOS and android. If I install a dart/flutter package to my project I got the error message below.

### Below is the error message

Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 14 Pro Max in debug mode...
Running pod install...
Error output from CocoaPods:
↳
WARNING: CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding.
Consider adding the following to ~/.profile:

```
    export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
    
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/unicode_normalize/normalize.rb:141:in `normalize': Unicode Normalization not appropriate for ASCII-8BIT (Encoding::CompatibilityError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:166:in `unicode_normalize'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:166:in `installation_root'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:226:in `podfile_path'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:105:in `markdown_podfile'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:30:in `report'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:66:in `report_error'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:396:in `handle_exception'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:337:in `rescue in run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:324:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro Max.

### Below is the information from flutter doctor -v

memmcol@memmcols-MBP demo % flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.6, on macOS 13.4.1 22F770820d darwin-x64, locale en-NG)
• Flutter version 3.10.6 on channel stable at /Users/memmcol/development/flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision f468f3366c (8 days ago), 2023-07-12 15:19:05 -0700
• Engine revision cdbeda788a
• Dart version 3.0.6
• DevTools version 2.23.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
• Android SDK at /Users/memmcol/Library/Android/sdk
• Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
• Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b802.4-9586694)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3.1)
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Build 14E300c
• CocoaPods version 1.12.1

[✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome)
! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b802.4-9586694)

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
• iPhone 14 Pro Max (mobile) • 99935478-7F27-4F63-A005-89ABC3F5B1DA • ios        • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-16-4 (simulator)
• macOS (desktop)            • macos                                • darwin-x64 • macOS 13.4.1 22F770820d darwin-x64

[✓] Network resources
• All expected network resources are available.

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.

### I run the command below on my terminal

flutter run. I am expecting my code to execute on iOS but it failed with error message tag to this question.

Below are some of the solutions online that I have tried but they are not working for me

### Solution One

1. cd ios
2. pod cache clean --all
3. pod clean
4. pod deintegrate
5. sudo gem install cocoapods-deintegrate cocoapods-clean
6. sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
7. arch -x86_64 pod repo update
8. arch -x86_64 pod install.

### Solution two

1. flutter clean
2. rm -Rf ios/Pods
3. rm -Rf ios/.symlinks
4. rm -Rf ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework
5. rm -Rf ios/Flutter/Flutter.podspec
6. flutter pub get
7. cd ios
8. pod install
9. arch -x86_64 pod install
10. cd ..
11. flutter build ios
12. flutter run

Comment: This question may be a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59405671/ios-cocoapods-requires-your-terminal-to-be-using-utf-8-encoding-after-latest

Comment: Does the solution given helps?

Comment: Thank you very much @Lucie, the reference solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The Solution to the Question above

1. Open command terminal on your Mac PC.
2. Navigate to your project root folder or Open terminal in your android studio.
3. Type `locale`.

You will get the response
`LANG=""`
`LC_COLLATE="C"`
`LC_CTYPE="C"`
`LC_MESSAGES="C"`
`LC_MONETARY="C"`
`LC_NUMERIC="C"`
`LC_TIME="C"`
`LC_ALL=`

4. Convert the response above to en_US.UTF-8 by typing the command
   `$open ~/.zshrc`
5. Copy and paste the en_US.UTF-8 encoding to it.
   `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8`
   `export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8`
   `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8`
6. Hold `Command + s` (to save the .zshrc file) then after close it
7. Type `locale` command again to verify your changes.
8. Run your code `flutter run`. :) Happy coding!